# Can anyone point me to a reference for the Drupal $account->content array?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I've been digging around all morning and I can't find any reference that defines the account object.

In particular, I want to modify another drupal admin's user hook() function to change the way it works. Currently, it comes out as dt/dd pairs without any css classes or custom styles, and I need to be able to theme the content.

```
  function acidfree_user($op, &$edit, &$account, $category = NULL) {
    if ($op == 'view') {
    //Pachkov.Sergey.START - MODIFIED BY MHEINZ
      $result = db_query("SELECT nid, title FROM node WHERE nid IN (SELECT nid FROM node WHERE uid=%d 
                         AND type='acidfree') ORDER BY nid desc", $account->uid);

      $i=0;
      $account->content['acidfree-albums'] = array(
        '#type' => 'user_profile_category',
        '#title' => t('Photo albums'),
      );
      while ($item = db_fetch_array($result)) {
        $title_node = $item['title'];
        $nid = $item['nid'];
        $account->content['acidfree-albums'][$i] = array(
                '#title' => t(' '),
                '#value' => l($title_node, "node/{$nid}"),
                '#class' => 'acidfree-albums',
                '#type' => 'user_profile_item',
        );
        $i++;
      }
    }
    //Pachkov.Sergey.END - MODIFIED BY MHEINZ
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dt`/`dd` used to display the `$account->content` array you see in [`hook_user`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user-profile-item.tpl.php) come from the [`user-profile-item.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user-profile-item.tpl.php) template. Using [`template_preprocess_user_profile_item`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_user_profile_item/6) in your modules or theme, you can add attributes for these `dt`/`dd`.

If you need to change one of the items in the `$account->content` array, you should use [`hook_profile_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_profile_alter/6):

```
function MODULE_profile_alter(&$account) {
  $account->content['acidfree-albums']['#title'] = t('Awesome photos!');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best reference you can get is

```
print_r($account->content);
```

and to see the trace to your current location (to see where the object is set) you could use

```
debug_print_backtrace();
```

Comment: It's true that that will tell me what is currently in the structure, it won't tell me what's legal for the structure.

Comment: if it's a magic structure then you will have hard time to find out, but see where it's created and you can grep for this method to see where the objects parameters are added. Usually object maps to database table somehow if the information is persistent and then you can look at the table structure to see what's possible